# ipython notebook nbconvert - how to display html output

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I use `ipython nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to pdf` to get a pdf file of my notebook. The picture below shows the (latex-)generated output. How can I change the behavior of nbconvert so that it shows the rendered HTML and not the object string representation?

[image: This is how the pdf looks like! I'd like the output of Out[2]: to show 'hello']

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly through nbconvert, but you can convert --to html and then convert the html to pdf through the browser or other command line tool.

Comment: But the appearance is not the same when you generate it from html. I'd like to have the 'flavor' of a latex document

Comment: Any luck with that?